# animation in squeak smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, morphic

I have a simple morph in squeak smalltalk.
I want to move it from x1,y1  to x2,y2  (animation) with 5 seconds (or 10 seconds)

is there a build in way to create animation in squeak smalltalk ?

Comment: Have a look at the _Morphic_ chapter of _Squeak / Pharo by Example_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a built in way:

Make a subclass of Morph and implement the two methods

- stepTime (time between steps in milliseconds) and
- step (is sent to the morph in regular intervals of time)

A minimal example:

```
Morph subclass: #MovingMorph
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    category: 'MovingMorph'
```

MovingMorph>>stepTime

```
stepTime
    ^ 100
```

MovingMorph>>step

```
step
    self position: self position + (1@1)
```

Now open a MovingMorph in the World (`MovingMorph new openInWorld`) and control the animation with `startStepping` and `stopStepping`.

Answer (score 7):

While it is possible to show animations using Morphic stepping, the [Animations Project](https://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/hirschfeld/trac/SqueakCommunityProjects/wiki/animations) takes a bit further, and provides a simple interface to use short animations:

```
AnimPropertyAnimation new
   duration: 500;
   target: myMorph;
   property: #position; "There should be a message called #position:."
   startValue: 10@10;
   endValue: 100@100;
   start.
```

Things like fade-in or fade-out or similar are even simpler:

```
myMorph fadeOut.
```